# SEO and search result changes when switching to SSL on Joomla site?

Tags: https, seo, search-engines

I am thinking about purchasing an SSL certificate for a website.  The most noticeable difference for the user would be the `http` now becomes `https` and there is that lock icon in most browsers.  Will there be any adverse affects on the website's current SEO or recognition by search engines when I make the switch?

Also this is a Joomla site, which has an option in the settings to use SSL.  It is supposed to make it easier but not sure if it takes care of everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues to be aware of, like needing to implement redirects from the old http:// addresses to the equivalent https:// addresses. This document outlined the things to be aware of: http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/seo-for-https-with-s-like-secure